# Does dbt 0.21.0 on_schema_change requires --full-refresh?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

regarding the new
`on_schema_change='sync_all_columns'`
config I have a question. I tested it a bunch of times and it seems that on adding a new column it doesn't automatically insert data into it. Also it doesn't really perform on the datatype changes it implies.

```
{{
   config(
   materialized='incremental',
   on_schema_change='sync_all_columns',
   incremental_strategy='merge'
   )
}}
```

(https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models)

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the documentation:
*Incremental models can now be configured to include an optional on_schema_change parameter to enable additional control when incremental model columns change. These options enable dbt to continue running incremental models in the presence of schema changes, resulting in fewer --full-refresh scenarios and saving query costs.*

Looks like it shouldn't run full-refresh
link:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models#what-if-the-columns-of-my-incremental-model-change

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought as well. I've read that over and over.. And for obvious reasons casting strings into integers shouldn't work.

But I even get this error, changing NUMBER(1,0) to Number (2,1).



`Database Error in model test_model
  040052 (22000): SQL compilation error: cannot change column TEST_INT from type NUMBER(1,0) to NUMBER(2,1) because changing the scale of a number is not supported.`

Comment: Any chance this is related to Snowflake? Does full refresh help?

Comment: Yes a full refresh helps. I hope it is an issue with snowflake. 
Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel_T maybe the specific issue here is because you are trying to *increase* precision of a numeric column? Try changing from `NUMBER(2,1)` to `NUMBER(1,0)`. (BTW - I'm also working with snowflake and trying this new feature, but don't see any effect)